# BufferedInputStream is read until the end but "discards?" data

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have a BufferedInputStream which I want to debug. For such purpose I use this method (Log.d and Log.wtf are just Android-specific logging tools, other than that the behaviour should not be different from pure Java):

```
    public static final String toString(BufferedInputStream is) {
    String ret = "";
    int readBytes = 0;

    is.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    if (is != null) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();

        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.wtf("NX4", "Should never happen!", e);
            }
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                readBytes += n;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.wtf("NX4", "Should never happen!", e);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                is.reset();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.wtf("NX4", "Should never happen!", e);
            }
        }
        ret = writer.toString();
    }

    Log.d("NX4", "Read bytes: " + readBytes);

    return ret;
}
```

When I run with for example, [this online XML file against which I'm testing right now](http://feed43.com/lolnews_euw_en.xml), and at the same time I download the file manually to my desktop in order to compare both the output of the above method and the original file, something happens that I can not understand at all:

1. The method properly reads 5664 bytes (info from the Log.d(...) call).
2. The original file has 5664 characters, which makes sense with the first fact.
3. The output of the above method has a length of only 4254 characters!

I think this could be somehow related to weird spacing issues which I don't know why but are happening, and it's needless to say that I have no idea on how to stop:

[image: Comparison of the original file and the output of the method]

**EDIT** Added BufferedInputStream creation snippet.

```
    URL source = new URL(srcString);
    URLConnection urlConnection = source.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I couldn't relate the images in the OP.How they differ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "OP". There are two differences: the first one is that the output of the method "features" a margin which I've highlighted within a white rectangle, and in addition the output is shorter (as I mention in the post, for some reason it has 1.4k chars less than it should).

Comment: I've dowloaded the xml and run your code but the output is the same as input, same length and same content. How is created the BufferedInputStream in input?

Comment: @aris3148880 Thanks. I've made an edit on the post to include the creation of the BufferedInputStream object.

Comment: You're right. A bunch of "true" are shown, but then a "false" pops up. Can this be because it's trying to read more data that it has been downloaded already or something like that?

Comment: Jorge I've deleted my comment on ready state cause it's incompatible with the problem.

Comment: Logging the read bytes shows 5664 the last time, which I guess is why the ready state turns into false.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Any other idea of what it can be? In the meantime I'm going to setup a pure Java project to check it out on its own.

Comment: No idea at the moment. My test is a pure Java project too. What is your real scenario?

Comment: Works like a charm in Java for me too. JDK 1.7. Same version that I'm using for the project in Android, minSDK API level 14.

Comment: Is it your bad content a copy and paste result from any console? Sorry for the trivial question but I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455986/urlconnection-cannot-retrive-complete-html

Comment: It is. Gonna dump it to a file, but looks like probably it's gonna be that. I'm stupid >.<

Comment: I'm having quite a lot of trouble to be able to find the file that I'm creating in order to make the check, but I'm quite sure that you got the point. If you want to copy your comment as answer I'll be glad to accept it, and sorry for the disturbance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the bad content is a copy and paste result from any console. 
Check this: [URLConnection cannot retrive complete Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455986/urlconnection-cannot-retrive-complete-html)